# Send Keyboard Shortcut to Application

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

I'm running Pithos (Pandora Client) on Ubuntu and you can hit <kbd>CTtrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to love a song or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to ban a song.  I also have a Microsoft ergonomic keyboard that has different options on top (like Web/Home, Search, Mail, Calculator, etc).

I was wondering if there's a way that you can map one of the buttons up on top to send a keyboard shortcut to an application (like Pithos) so I can like/not like a song, while not losing focus on the active application window.